# Regex to match a string anywhere in url

Tags: regex

I'm trying to make a regex that i can use to match http referrers that contain a certain word anywhere in the domain portion (and not the path portion).

I've gotten the following to work, only problem is it only matches when the word im searching for exists at the start of the string.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]\.)?(<example>\.)?(?<example>.+)$
```

Any idea how i can have the word example match anywhere in the domain (1st level and 2nd level) and still retain the domain name format (something.something.something or something.something) ?

Comment: post a sample input and expected output.

Comment: What is the language? If the language can parse URL, use it to extract domain before doing matches.

Comment: Im using it in rewrite rules of a web server (it uses Apache style syntax)

Comment: Please show some examples of URLs you want to search and the strings you want to find within them.